# SSRS Report rendering old version when viewed from external domain

Tags: asp.net-mvc, web, reporting-services

I have a SSRS report which is deployed as a local report to the MVC application on an outward facing web server, using Report Viewer and aspx page. The report runs fine when we access the web site from inside the company network (the wifi). However, when we access the app from external site (for eg. my home wifi), I dont get the same report - I get an old version which I had changed many weeks ago. I am not sure where it could be cached. Any help s greatly appreciated.

Thanks!